# How to Find coordinates Canvas use extension Coords Firefox?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

How to Find coordinates Canvas use extension Coords  Firefox?
I have problem find coordinates from Canvas Online-Calculator https://www.online-calculator.com/full-screen-calculator/
can you help me How to use  Coords to find Coordinates from Canvas Online-Calculator ?
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
"G:\Project\calculator\calculator\chromedriver.exe");

```
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get("https://www.online-calculator.com/full-screen-calculator/");
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("fullframe")));
            WebElement canvas = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("canvas")));
         new Actions(driver).moveToElement(canvas, 0, 0).moveByOffset(454, 210).click()
                            .build()
                            .perform();
```

Comment: tag your binding language, also share any code that you might have tried.

Comment: I add now my code , but not working I use extension Coords Firefox ,  I don't know Coordinates is correct or not I try in selenium but not working  , can you help me how to find correct coordinates to find button Click like 2 + 2 = or else, I just need know  how to use Coords in Canvas correct , if you can demo video or gif , that's very helpful